# How to express something that happens currently, but that might be fixed in the future?

Tags: adjectives, present-tense, adverbial-phrases, redundancy

I'm not sure if I wrote my sentence correctly: *At the time the thesis is written, one current shortcoming of the proxy tables is that*.

I want to say, that currently, when I'm writing the thesis, there is a shortcoming which could be fixed later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

> At the time of writing, one shortcoming of the proxy tables is that...

Alternatively you could rely on your readers to understand that all theses report on the status quo, and cannot divine the future. Consequently you could simply say

> Currently one shortcoming of the proxy tables is that ...

Or

> At present, one shortcoming of the proxy tables is that...

Comment: I like the first version more, thanks! I had it like your second suggestion says, but my supervisor suggested to write it explicitely.

Comment: Another consideration: is the problem with the proxy tables, or with the use of them? If it is the proxy tables which are to be improved, OP should write "A shortcoming with the current proxy tables".

Comment: Personally, I normally omit the definite article in the first usage *(at time of writing)*. And perhaps more informally, I'd often use *as I write*.